# Getting NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 laravel

Tags: laravel

I am learning laravel. I tried this simple routing

```
Route::get('con/{dam}',function ($dam){
$user= $dam;
return $user;
});
```

And I'm getting error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is dam suppose to be the model? so your model is named Dam?

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: How you can call, please give url. If $dam is eloquent model then Pass Model name in function argument before $dam